# Return the first record that is logged in each one second window from X. X+1, X+2, X+3, X+4, etc

Tags: mysql, loops, select

I'll try my best to explain my bizzare situation. I have a bunch of data logged to the tenth of a second. An event occurs almost every second from time X. Every second is considered an "event window". The time logged is the elapsed time from X. Using the first record as a "seed", I only need to return the first record that is logged in each one second window from X. X+1, X+2, X+3, X+4, etc.

```
targets
--------------------------
| id  | time  | name     |
|-----|------ |-----------
| 1   |  1.0  | target01 |
| 2   |  1.1  | target01 |
| 3   |  1.2  | target01 |
| 4   |  1.3  | target01 |
| 5   |  1.4  | target01 |
| 6   |  1.5  | target01 |
| 7   |  1.6  | target01 |
| 8   |  1.7  | target01 |
| 9   |  1.8  | target01 |
| 10  |  1.9  | target01 |
| 11  |  2.0  | target01 |
| 12  |  2.1  | target01 |
| 13  |  2.2  | target01 |
```

...

```
| 50  |  4.9  | target01 |
| 51  |  5.3  | target01 |
| 52  |  5.4  | target01 |
| 53  |  5.5  | target01 |
| 54  |  5.6  | target01 |
| 55  |  5.7  | target01 |
| 56  |  5.8  | target01 |
| 57  |  5.9  | target01 |
| 58  |  6.0  | target01 |
| 59  |  6.1  | target01 |
| 60  |  6.2  | target01 |
| 61  |  6.3  | target01 |
| 62  |  6.4  | target01 |
--------------------------
```

How would I get this in return:

```
--------------------------
| id  | time  | name     |
|-----|------ |-----------
| 1   |  1.0  | target01 |
| 11  |  2.0  | target01 |
| 21  |  3.0  | target01 |
| 31  |  4.0  | target01 |
| 51  |  5.3  | target01 |
| 58  |  6.0  | target01 |
--------------------------
```

Notice that record 51 is at 5.3 seconds. It is the first record that falls within that four second window (X+4).

Horrible database planning but I am stuck inheriting the mess. Thoughts?

Comment: What are the column types?

Comment: Does it need to specifically be the _first_ record logged in each one-second window? The simplest strategy I can think of is doing some sort of time column conversion to drop the decimal portion and selecting only records with unique values in that column, but I don't think that will get you the _first_ record for each window...

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately the first record is the most critical. The 5.3 timestamp actually matters.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
select * from (
    select * from targets
    order by time) x
group by floor(time)
```

[See this working on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4f76/2)

Comment: This query does not provide any guarantee that the rows returned will be the rows with the lowest time.  To demonstrate this, a test case where the rows are not "ordered" in the table, inserting the rows in a different order, where the "lowest time" row is not the first row for a given second.

Comment: @spencer7593 wait you're right. fixed. I'll change the SQLFiddle data too.

Comment: the test case i described demonstrates that the problem is really that the `ORDER BY` gets executed later in the execution plan than the `GROUP BY` does.

Comment: @spencer7593 but not any more, right? My current query orders, *then* groups

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to make use of the `FLOOR` and `COALESCE` functions

```
SELECT FLOOR(time) AS whole_second, COALESECE(id), COALESCE(time), COALESCE(name)
FROM table
GROUP BY whole_second
ORDER BY whole_second ASC
```

Comment: Why are you using coalesce? It has only one parameter, so it's doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

Given that `time` column is numeric, and there are no "duplicate" values for `time`, then something like this will work:

```
SELECT d.id
     , d.time
     , d.name
  FROM mytable d
  JOIN ( SELECT MIN(t.time) AS `time`
           FROM mytable t
          GROUP BY FLOOR(t.time)
       ) m
    ON m.time = d.time
 ORDER BY d.time
```

(With that query, if there are "duplicate" values for a lowest `time` for a second, then both of those rows will be returned.  This could be addressed with a simple `GROUP BY` on the outermost query, as long as it's arbitrary as to which of those rows is returned.

(That query will return the resultset you specified.  It's not clear if you wanted this "by name" as well, so I omitted that.

---

Note that there are some other approaches, some of which will perform much better on large sets.

---

Another (MySQL-specific) approach makes use of user variables:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.time
     , t.name
  FROM ( SELECT s.id
              , s.time
              , s.name
              , @prev AS `prev_sec`
              , @prev := FLOOR(s.time) AS `this_sec`
           FROM targets s
           JOIN (SELECT @prev := '') p
          ORDER BY s.time
       ) t
 WHERE prev_sec <> this_sec
```

(Exercise caution with user variables in SQL statements. It's possible to construct statements where the behavior is predictable, but sometimes the behavior is "unexpected", if one doesn't understand the execution plan, the order the steps are run in, and in which step the variables will get set.

---

Another (usually slower performing) alternative is to make use of a `NOT EXISTS` predicate to exclude rows for which there is an "earlier" time within the same second.

Sometimes an approach like this one can be faster against large tables IF the query is pulling a small set of time values (i.e. a tight range of rows, such as one hours worth of rows out of a years worth of data) and IF an appropriate index is available, especially a covering index, or a at least an index with `time` as a leading column.

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.time
     , t.name
  FROM targets t
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM targets e
          WHERE e.time >= FLOOR(t.time)
            AND e.time < t.time
       )
 ORDER
    BY t.time
```

(This query, like the first one given in the answer, will also return two or more rows with duplicate `time` values if those `time` values are the lowest for any second.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select *
from targets t
where time % 1 = (
  select min(time % 1) 
  from targets 
  where floor(time) = floor(t.time))
```

[SQLFidddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02a10/8)

Answer (score 0):

You need analytic function like [Rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx), but I'm pretty sure MySQL doesn't do that.

```
select Id, Time, Name
from
(
    SELECT Id, Time, Name, 
           Rank() OVER(PARTITION BY Floor(time) ORDER BY time Asc) AS Rank
    FROM  @aTable
) SubSelect
where Rank = 1
```

[You can see an example on data.stackexchange.com.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/89397/return-the-first-record-that-is-logged-in-each-one-second-window-from-x-x1-x2)

Comment: you are correct, MySQL does not have the RANK() or any of the "analytic functions" available in other DBMS.  An analytic function is not needed to obtain the resultset.